# Use gcloud metadata-from-file shutdown-script to stop docker container gracefully

Tags: linux, docker, gcloud

I have created `gcloud` compute instance from docker image and configured it to launch [shutdown script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript) which should call `docker stop` in order to shut down the app in the container gracefully.

```
gcloud beta compute instances create-with-container mycontainername \
    --container-image ypapax/trap_exit \
    --metadata-from-file shutdown-script=./on_shutdown.sh
```

And here is my initital on_shutdown.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Although, I added more debugging lines to it and now `on_shutdown.sh` looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript
curl -X POST -d "$(date) running containers on $(hostname): $(docker ps)" http://trap_exit.requestcatcher.com/test
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
result=$?
curl -X POST -d "$(date) $(hostname) stop status code: $result" http://trap_exit.requestcatcher.com/test
```

When I reboot the google compute instance:

```
sudo reboot
```

The script `on_shutdown.sh` is launched (I see it checking [requrest listener](http://trap_exit.requestcatcher.com/)). But when it tries to stop docker container, there is nothing to stop yet, `docker ps` shows empty line.

So this line:

```
curl -X POST -d "$(date) running containers on $(hostname): $(docker ps)" http://trap_exit.requestcatcher.com/test
```

gives me

```
Thu Jul 12 04:29:48 UTC 2018 running containers on myinstance:
```

Before calling `sudo reboot` I checked `docker ps` and saw my container running:

```
$ docker ps     
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
bbaba30e65ff        ypapax/trap_exit    "/entrypoint.sh"    7 seconds ago       Up 7 seconds                            myinstance
```

So looks like docker container is killed between calling `reboot` and launching `on_shutdown.sh`. The problem is that killing doesn't call `trap cleanup EXIT` in my [entrypoint](https://github.com/ypapax/shutdown_script/blob/master/entrypoint.sh). It needs to be stopped in order to call the cleanup.
Here is my entry point:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -ex

cleanup(){
    echo cleanup is called
    curl -X POST -d "cleanup is called on $(hostname) $(date)" http://trap_exit.requestcatcher.com/test
}

trap cleanup EXIT
curl -X POST -d "container is started on $(hostname) $(date)" http://trap_exit.requestcatcher.com/test
sleep 10000
```

So I would like to run my container's cleanup on gcloud compute instance reboot or shutdown but flag `--metadata-from-file shutdown-script=./on_shutdown.sh` doesn't help to do it. I also tried other methods to call a script on reboot like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48974/47116). But my script hadn't been launched at all.

Here is my [Dockerfile](https://github.com/ypapax/shutdown_script/blob/master/Dockerfile) if it could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there are [limitations coming with this approach](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript#limitations):

> - Create and run shutdown scripts that execute commands right before an instance is terminated or restarted, on a best-effort basis.
> - Shutdown scripts are especially useful for instances in a [managed instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/manager) with an [autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler).
> - The script runs during the [limited shutdown period](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript#time_period) before the instance stops

As you have seen, docker might already have stopped by the time the shutdown script run: check with `docker ps -a` (instead of docker ps) to see the status of all exited containers.
Try [adding a supervisor](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) (as [in this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/jenkins-packer-agent/blob/master/Dockerfile#L54-L57)) a docker image itself, in order to see if the supervisor, or at least [use the `docker run --init` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#specify-an-init-process): the goal is to check if the containers themselves do use their supervisor scripts.

Comment: thx, supervisord helped a lot, and I don't even need to use `--metadata-from-file shutdown-script`

Comment: @MaximYefremov Great! Don't hesitate to post an answer of your own, detailing what you ended up doing in your case.

Comment: @MaximYefremov do you mind explaining what you've done to solve the issue? I have the same problem and don't know how the supervisor could help with that. Thanks!